# Matplotlib - Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have produced the graph below using matplotlib library in jupyter python. As you can see I have two different data, one is red and the other is green. My question is, is there any way I can have a small side window that states what each color means?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is good function for that  called matplotlib.pyplot.legend()

I recommend checking this: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I was looking for.